# Error in using Stimulsoft reports.js in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stimulsoft

I use react.
for add stimulsoft reports.js, first add necessary link to css and javascript files in my Index.html file :

```
<link href="Css/stimulsoft.viewer.office2013.whiteblue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script src="Scripts/stimulsoft.reports.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/stimulsoft.reports.maps.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/stimulsoft.viewer.js"></script>
```

After that i create a Component with this code :

```
 import React from 'react';
    class Viewer extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <div id="viewerContent"></div>;
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            var report = new window.Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
            //create error
            report.loadFile("MyReportFile.mrt");

            var options = new window.Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewerOptions();

            this.viewer = new window.Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(options, "StiViewer", false);
            this.viewer.report = report;
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.viewer.renderHtml("viewerContent");
        }

    }

    export default Viewer;
```

and loadFile method caused below error in console :

```
 stimulsoft.reports.js:73 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is 
        deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check 
        https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

    Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDashboard' of undefined
    at stimulsoft.viewer.js:11
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: It seems like the library is making a request to a server and expects the response to be json but it isn't. Open the network tab in your developer toolbar and run the application again. Then inspect the response and see what it contains and what the status code is.

Comment: oh...the error was because the report file was not addressed to the Index file.instead it addressed to Component Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I reached the Stimulsoft report in reactjs by this two steps :

**First step** - Add Stimulsoft report Js files in HTML file in the public folder :

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
<!-- Title -->

<!-- Favicon & Manifest -->

<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.viewer.office2013.whiteblue.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.engine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.export.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.import.xlsx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.dashboards.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.blockly.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/reports/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.viewer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Second step** - create jsx component and copy this code to the component :

Viewer.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
export default (props) => {
useEffect(() => {
if (props.show == true) {

  var options = new window.Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewerOptions();

  // options.appearance.fullScreenMode = true;
  // options.height = "100%";
  // options.appearance.scrollbarsMode = true;
  // options.toolbar.showDesignButton = true;

  var viewer = new window.Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(
    options,
    "StiViewer",
    false
  );

  var report = new window.Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
  report.licenseKey = "licenseKey ";

  report.loadFile(props.templateFile);
  var dataSet = new window.Stimulsoft.System.Data.DataSet("Demo");
  dataSet.readJson(props.dataSet);
  report.dictionary.databases.clear();

  report.regData("Demo", "Demo", dataSet);
  viewer.report = report;

  viewer.renderHtml("viewer");
}
}),
[]; 
return (
<>
  <div id="viewer"></div>
</>
);
};
```